# NASM PePacker - Reading little endian binary data from array into structs

Tags: c++, winapi, nasm, endianness, portable-executable

when I copy the binary data from an .exe into an array then it's in little endian. In C++ that is no problem:

```
char data[100] = {0x4d, 0x5a, 0x90, ...} 
PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER IDH;
IDH = PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER(data);
printf("%d", IDH->e_magic);
```

The output is:

```
23117 in dec / 0x5a4d in hex
```

So it seems like that the compiler is doing the conversion from little endian to big endian automatically.

But when I want to convert this code in assembly(NASM) then that will most likely not be the case.

Assume that `IMAGE_DOS_HEADER` is already declared and null initialized and `PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER` is a pointer to the first element of the struct. And data is initialized as `data db 4dh, 5ah, 90h, ...`

Now: When I assign a value to the structs elements by doing:

```
mov eax, [data]
mov [PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER], eax

mov eax, [data+2]
mov [PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER+2], eax

...
```

Then I guess it will be assigned as little endian and so have the value `0x4d5a` instead of `0x5a4d`

How do I prevent this?

Comment: First of all you want `mov ax, [data]` and `mov [PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER], ax` (same with the one after it). You are moving 4 bytes of data around using EAX when it is a WORD (16-bit value). Registers don't have endianness, memory does. If you do `mov ax, [data]` it will load a 16-bit value into AX. The low byte in memory will be the low 8 bits of AX and the  byte after it will be the high byte of AX. When printing the 16-bit value AX out in HEX it would appear as 0x5a4d.

Comment: However you can move the first 4 bytes at one time. The structure starts with WORD e_magic WORD e_cblp. If you do `mov eax, [data]
mov [PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER], eax` you automatically have moved the first 2 fields of the structure. The first 4 bytes stored at `data` will be the same bytes in the same order as stored in PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER

Comment: For clarity I think you should use `IDN` as the label name in assembly as `PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER` really is the name of a type. NASM doesn't care though, just from a human readability perspective I'd make the change.

Comment: "I guess it will be assigned as little endian and so have the value 0x4d5a" that is actually big endian. In little endian the first byte in memory is the least significant part of the word.